# Sitecore.Exceptions.ConfigurationException:'Could not create instance of type:Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.No matching constructor was found.'

Tags: fakedb

I have implemented Xunit unit testing (ver 2.4.1) with Sitecore.FakeDb (ver 2.0.1) in Sitecore 9.3 version. After implementation when I run the test I am getting below exception.

```
Sitecore.Exceptions.ConfigurationException: 'Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider. No matching constructor was found.'

**Stack Trace:**

   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetProviders[TProvider,TCollection](List`1 nodes)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetProviders[TProvider,TCollection](String rootPath, TProvider& defaultProvider)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.ProviderHelper`2.ReadProviders()
   at Sitecore.Configuration.ProviderHelper`2.get_Provider()
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.get_FallbackProvider()
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.GetItem(String itemPath, Language language, Version version, Database database, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.GetItem(String itemPath, Language language, Version version, Database database)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.GetItem(String itemPath, Language language, Version version, Database database)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a list of breaking changes between Sitecore 9.2 and 9.3 so you have to upgrade FakeDb to v3 (see [release notes](https://github.com/sshushliapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/releases)).

JFI, for 9.3 FakeDb is [no longer needed](https://blog.sshushliapin.io/2019/12/25/switching-from-fakedb-to-mocks.html). You can easily mock Sitecore API.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detail.

Comment: Can we use Moq for Item Axes?  I have converted to my code from Nsubstitue to Moq.

Nsubstitue:
var item = Substitute.For<Item>(id, itemData, database);
item.Axes.Returns(Substitute.For<ItemAxes>(item));
return item;

Moq:
 var item = new Mock<Item>(id, itemData, database);
 item.Axes.Returns(new Mock<ItemAxes>(item));           
return item;

I am getting error in Moq.

Comment: How it's related to the current question? I suggest you to create a new question and show your code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance!!!